# Scroller not work under custom layout in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

I've created a custom layout and apply like code given below:

```
 <mx:Accordion x="10" y="10" width="292" height="417">
      <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Electronics Symbols">
        <s:Scroller x="0" y="0" width="200" height="300">
            <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:layout>
                    <local:gridLayout/>
                </s:layout>


                <inductors:Inductor mouseDown="mouseDown(event)"/>
                <inductors:IronCoreInductor mouseDown="mouseDown(event)"/>
                <inductors:LongInductor mouseDown="mouseDown(event)"/>
                <inductors:VariableInductor mouseDown="mouseDown(event)"/>

                `
```

here gridLayout is my custom layout.when i use flex layouts scroller works but on this layout it does not working.

Comment: try setting clipAndEnableScrolling="true" on the Group

Answer (score 0):

Just need to wrap a  around whatever components you use under the NavigatorContent.

Comment: how i wrap? did u get problem?